# How to get the mime data from the DataHandler

Tags: java, soap, apache-axis, mime, mtom

I send a soap message using MTOM by Axis2, and i monitor the soap get the message below:

```
--MIMEBoundaryurn_uuid_5C5747FDE5329B8CEB1280130156514
 Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
 Content-ID: <0.urn:uuid:5C5747FDE5329B8CEB1280130156515@apache.org>

 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><ns1:EventMessage xmlns:ns1="http://www.iec.ch/TC57/2008/schema/message"><ns1:Header><ns1:Verb>created</ns1:Verb><ns1:Noun>NetwordDataSet</ns1:Noun></ns1:Header><ns1:Payload><ns1:Compressed><xop:Include href="cid:1.urn:uuid:5C5747FDE5329B8CEB1280130159937@apache.org" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" /></ns1:Compressed><ns1:format>RDF</ns1:format></ns1:Payload></ns1:EventMessage></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
 --MIMEBoundaryurn_uuid_5C5747FDE5329B8CEB1280130156514
 Content-Type: text/plain
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
 Content-ID: <1.urn:uuid:5C5747FDE5329B8CEB1280130159937@apache.org>

 测试一把
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5








 --MIMEBoundaryurn_uuid_5C5747FDE5329B8CEB1280130156514--
```

In the server side i got the code using code generation tools, but the dataHandler is null. And the code like this:

```
 public void publishEvent
              (
              ch.iec.www.tc57._2008.schema.message.EventMessage eventMessage
              )
        throws FaultMessage{
            //TODO : fill this with the necessary business logic

                EventMessageType emt = eventMessage.getEventMessage();

                 PayloadType plt = emt.getPayload();

                 DataHandler dataHandler =  plt.getPayloadTypeChoice_type0().getCompressed();




                 if(dataHandler!=null){....}
              }
```

I fixed it.

It's about my XSD

```
       <xs:choice>
            <xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="skip" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>For XML payloads</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:any>
            <xs:element name="Compressed" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>For compressed and/or binary, uuencoded payloads</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
```

When i delete the `<xs:choice>` portion of the XSD,  i can get the dataHandler. not supported?